# Connecting with the db only through javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, database

```
var mysql    = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : '',
  password : '',
  database : 'mejili'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * FROM cards where number = 1', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (!err)
    console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
  else
    console.log('Error while performing Query.');
});
```

I have searched a lot and I still cant find a way to connect with the db only through js, not using node.

Comment: You can't connect to a MySQL database with only plain javascript.. Plain javascript only has API's for WebSQL.

Comment: @RaymondNijland let's hope to do it!

Comment: I cant but wonder, why would you need to connect your db using only JS?

Comment: cause the code so fc complicated with kockoutjs that it stinks